# Dispatch self action in a timeout

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

For some reason I cannot call the same function within a timeout.. if this wasn't an Action function it works just fine.. is this just not possible?  I just want to make sure so I can move on or make a hack... thank you

```
export function initialize () {
  return function ( dispatch ) {

    if ( window.someAPIVar ) {
      console.log( 'done' );
    }
    else {
      console.log( 'looping' );
      //setTimeout( dispatch( initialize ), 250 );  // does not work
      //setTimeout( initialize, 250 );  // does not work
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: For future reference, "does not work" is a very weak description of a problem. Why doesn't it work? What are you expecting? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setTimeout( initialize, 250 );
```

This will do nothing, since `initialize` is a function which returns another function. So after 250ms, setTimeout will invoke this function and you will not notice anything.

```
setTimeout( dispatch( initialize ), 250 );
```

The above will also not do anything useful. `dispatch( initialize )` is executed immediately and the function it returns is what will be called after 250ms, which is not what you want. It looks like what you meant to do here is this:

```
setTimeout( () => dispatch( initialize() ), 250 );
```

You need to pass a function which calls `dispatch`, and `dispatch` needs to receive the value of an action creator, which will either be an object like `{ type: 'SOME_ACTION', payload: 1 }` or a function like `dispatch => dispatch({ type: 'SOME_ACTION', payload: 1 })`.

If this is a little confusing, read through the examples on the redux-thunk GitHub page at https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk.

Comment: it worked perfectly.  i just forgot the () => as you pointed out.  ty